# Setting up my router with a static ip

Tags: networking, router

I have a single static IP. I currently set my nic card to this on my computer (with subnet mask and default gateway). But Id like to use more than one computer over network. 
Is it possible to set my router to have the static ip and have multiple computers connect? What sort of docmentation/keywords should I look for to learn more.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Look for NAT.

NAT is also the default on just about any SoHo *modem*. Chances are that you only need a simple device, configure the WAN side with the IP/mask/GW you already have and you are done.

> What sort of docmentation/keywords should I look for to learn more.

[Network address translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) on Wikipedia.